# Data conversion failed -"The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."

Tags: sql-server, debugging, ssis, etl, data-conversion

I have a simple data flow where I read data out of a table, do some data conversions, and load it into another table:

[image]

However when I run the package I get the following errors:

```
Error: 0xC02020C5 at Atish to CRM, Data Conversion [142]: Data conversion failed while converting column "CAMPAIGNID" (27) to column "Copy of CAMPAIGNID" (206).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
Error: 0xC0209029 at Atish to CRM, Data Conversion [142]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Copy of CAMPAIGNID]" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Copy of CAMPAIGNID]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Error: 0xC0047022 at Atish to CRM, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Data Conversion" (142) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Data Conversion Input" (143). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

My mappings:

[image]

Lastly since the error seems to be complaining about 'CAMPAIGNID', the datatype of it on the **destination** table is **uniqueidentifier**. I honestly don't know what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 2):

You are converting `CAMPAIGNNAME` to `uniqueidentifier` and `CAMPAIGNID` to `string[DT_STR]`. However your description seems to indicate that `CAMPAIGNID` must be `uniqueidentifier`

Also as per the error, your settings seem to indicate `Failure on error`. If you are sure that the conversion is correct and there will be no truncation, then you can change that property to `Ignore on error`. Alternately, you can use `Error output` and redirect it to another destination and inspect the results.

Also it is unclear why you are converting all the columns. Adding datatypes of your source and destination columns might add more clarity.

Comment: Sorry, please see updated error messages and screenshot of mappings. That was an honest mistake when preparing my post.

Comment: Please also add your input data types

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumble on this dreaded error, and if you are trying to convert a GUID which is in string format to a uniqueidentifier column, the chances are your string GUIDs are not wrapped in {}. Try adding curly brackets around your GUIDs and try to run it. The potential data loss message should go away.